# NodeJS mongo - Refer to uniquely generated links for click function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the current code I have, this generates a list of 'teams' I have in my database to print to the page. Please note the HTML code is written using .jade's template, but it is easy enough to understand what is happening

Team.jade

```
div.teamList
                    form.form-horizontal(action='/team', id="teamForm")
                        div.control-group
                            label.control-label(for="teamId") Team Id:
                            div.controls
                                input#teamId.input-small(type="text")
                        div.control-group
                            label.control-label(for="teamName") Team Name:
                            div.controls
                                input#teamName.input-small(type="text")
                        div.control-group
                            div.controls
                                button#teamUpdate.btn.btn-primary.btn-mini(type="submit", value="Update Team") Update
                        div.control-group
                            label.control-label(for="newTeamName") Enter new team:
                            div.controls
                                input#newTeamName.input-small(type="text")
                        div.control-group
                            div.controls
                                button#teamConfirm.btn.btn-primary.btn-mini(type="submit", value="Save Team") Submit
                br
                div.teamList(style='border: none; background: #cecece; color: #1a1a1a; padding: 4px; width: 400px; height: 315px; overflow: auto;')
                    include showTeams
```

showTeams.jade

```
div#teamListDiv
    - if(allTeams.length > 0){
        table
            thead
                tr
                    th Name
            tbody
                tr
                    td
                        - each team in allTeams
                            include teamDisplay
    - } else {
        h3 No teams till now..
    - }
```

teamDisplay.jade

```
div.teams(id="team-#{team.key}")
  p #{team.name}
```

At the moment this will generate a list of all the teams in the database when `showTeams` is ran. The `teamDisplay` file will generate a new div for each team with the `key` as the name of the div.

Instead of generating `p #{team.name}` inside the div, I want to generate a link, which is easy enough to do. But when the link is clicked, I want the `teamId` and `teamName` textboxes to be filled with the corresponding data.

I have this in team.js:

```
Team.initIndexPage = function(){
    $('#teamConfirm').click(function(){
        submitTeam();
    });

    submitTeam = function(){
        // frontend sends data - backend parses the data
        var teamForm = {
            name : $('#newTeamName').val()
        };
        // Basic validation
        $.post('/save/team', {'teamForm' : teamForm}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        });
    };

};
```

As you can see I am referring to `#teamConfirm` to submit a new team, so my question is...how would I refer to a situation where ANY of the team links are clicked...that it fills the textboxes with the correct data?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% followed everything you said - but it doesn't seem like your issue has much to do with node/mongo, and its more of a front-end javascript problem. If you want to keep track of which link is being clicked you can use javascript's 'this' context.

So if you gave all of the links a common class name and changed your code in team.js to work something like this:

```
$('.teamLink').click(function(){
    submitTeam($(this)); // $(this) keeps track of the actual link that was clicked.
});
```

You could then grab that context in submitTeam() and use it to manipulate the element however you'd like.

Comment: I have a list of links generated using a team's key as the id for each link, I basically want to fill the textboxes with the information for whichever team was clicked.

Comment: Not sure how to apply your code to my problem though if you could explain further please? I am looking to use showTeam() as a function when the link is clicked, in order to put the team's key and name into the text fields.

Comment: Okay. I think maybe I misunderstood your question, tell me if this is closer to your issue: You are using your showTeams template to put the team's key/name into the text fields, but instead of doing this on page load, you'd rather do this when the user clicks on a specific link. Is that correct?

Comment: ShowTeams is used to take each team in the database and create a list showing every team, I have generated the list of teams as links, each link is called team-#{team.key}. When a link is clicked I want the text boxes filled with the information of that team so that I can edit their details

Comment: Sorry, showteam the function is used when a link is clicked, but I don't know how to say "if any team is clicked fill the text box with its info"

Comment: Okay so I think there are actually 2 problems here. The first I tried to address in my original post, which is that you can use `$(this)` to identify _which_ link was clicked. After identifying the element, you want to expand it. The problem here is that showTeams is a template, not a function. The way node works showTeams.jade gets run when the page is rendered, and at that time the jade template gets converted into HTML. This means if you want to generate that HTML dynamically based on what was clicked, you need to use jQuery in submitTeam() to do that. I will edit my post to clarify this.

Comment: I'm using the links as I thought this was the easiest way to achieve this, click a team... Show teams details... Update team. Appears it's not so easy

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment, how would you recommend using which team was clicked to show that team's details?

Comment: Well it seems like you currently have the id of each team in the id of the element. You could use the `$(this)` element to extract the id, and then retrieve the data you need from the database in submitTeams(). If you want to be able to retrieve database info like this from the front-end you'll need to setup an API to get it, or use something like nowJS (https://github.com/Flotype/now). I think a simpler solution, however, would be to simply get all the data you need with your showTeams template when the page is loaded and use javascript to show/hide it when the user clicks a link.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm using mongoose/mongo/express at the moment. How would you extract the name of the id from the element that had been clicked? I would then want to use this to do something like `$('#teamName').val() = #{team.name}` but I don't have a way of using the id to know which tteamt is referring to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23394/discussion-between-bluemoon-and-germainelol)